# Sort Data on the basis of user_id

Tags: laravel

I have this function and i want to sort the data on the basis of user_id,

```
public function picklist_receive(Request $request, $id){
        $picklist_id = $id;
        $picklist = WmsPicklist::find($picklist_id);
        $sorted_user_id = array();
        if($picklist && $picklist->status == 0){
            $picklist_data = array();
            $product_ids = array();
          
            foreach($picklist->items as $item){

                $pending_picking = WmsPendingPicking::find($item->pending_picking_id);

                $picklist_data[$item->id]['pending_picking_id'] = $pending_picking->id;
                $picklist_data[$item->id]['product_id'] = $pending_picking->product_id;
                $picklist_data[$item->id]['sku_id'] = $pending_picking->product->sku_id;
                $picklist_data[$item->id]['product_name'] = $pending_picking->product->name;
                $picklist_data[$item->id]['shipper_name'] = $pending_picking->product->shipper->name;
                $picklist_data[$item->id]['listed_quantity'] = $pending_picking->quantity;
                if(!in_array($pending_picking->product_id, $product_ids)){
                    $product_ids[] = $pending_picking->product_id;
                }
            }
```

Table for WMSPendingpicking

```
 Schema::create('wms_pending_pickings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('leaf_id');
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->integer('shipment_id');
            $table->integer('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

(wms_products)table which has user_id

```
Schema::create('wms_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('sku_id');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->integer('buffer_quantity');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Can anyone help?? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the relation between `picklist` and `user` ?

Comment: there is no relation between the two

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your relation :

```
public function picklist_receive(Request $request, $id){
    $picklist = WmsPicklist::find($id);
    $sorted_user_id = [];
    $picklist_data = array();
    $product_ids = array();
    
    if($picklist && $picklist->status == 0){  
        foreach($picklist->items as $item){
            $pending_picking = WmsPendingPicking::find($item->pending_picking_id);

            $picklist_data[$item->id]['pending_picking_id'] = $pending_picking->id;
            $picklist_data[$item->id]['product_id'] = $pending_picking->product_id;
            $picklist_data[$item->id]['sku_id'] = $pending_picking->product->sku_id;
            $picklist_data[$item->id]['product_name'] = $pending_picking->product->name;
            $picklist_data[$item->id]['shipper_name'] = $pending_picking->product->shipper->name;
            $picklist_data[$item->id]['listed_quantity'] = $pending_picking->quantity;
            if(!in_array($pending_picking->product_id, $product_ids)){
                $product_ids[] = $pending_picking->product_id;
            }
            
            if (!isset($sorted_user_id[$pending_picking->product->user_id])) {
                $sorted_user_id[$pending_picking->product->user_id] = [];
            }
            if (!isset($sorted_user_id[$pending_picking->product->user_id][$item->id])) {
                $sorted_user_id[$pending_picking->product->user_id][$item->id] = $pending_picking;
            }
        }
    }
}
```